# Change background color from php code area JetBrains PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

i like to change the "blue" color from the coding area in PhpStorm. How can i do this ??

Here my Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It is not an off-topic question. Rules say "...unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming" - this is exactly what this question is about. Only good and experienced PHP programmers know how to answer this question - where do you suppose the man to post it instead if not in PHP area?

Comment: Change "blue" to what color? Change "white" color to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click Ctrl+~ (tilda sign, under Esc button) and then "Switch Color Scheme"

Comment: You were 4 secs fast :) +1

Comment: can you say the shortcut for mac :)

Comment: @OlegDubas hmm i need to change the color not the theme

Comment: Sure. Those are two different things. First "Switch look and feel" to, say, Windows. After doing that, "Switch color scheme" to Darkula, for example.